# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined mongoDB.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

In the terminal of my IntelliJ, I am able to call "node mongoDB.js" and retrieve the sample data in my database. However, when I go to launch the index.html page, I am given an error at the console screen of: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined mongoDB.js:1     at mongoDB.js:1"
I tried to see if the button wasn't working to javascript error but was able to get a hard-coded word to appear. Any help would be appreciated. Code below:

```
async function main() {
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://<usr>:<pass>@cluster0.dfgj3.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

    const client = new MongoClient(uri);

    try {
        await client.connect();

        await listDatabases(client);
    } catch (e){
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}

main().catch(console.error);

async function listDatabases(client) {
    const databasesList = await client.db().admin().listDatabases();
    console.log("Databases:");
    databasesList.databases.forEach(db => console.log(` - ${db.name}`));
};

 function displayQuery() {
    let text1 = "Hello";

    document.getElementById("query").innerHTML = text1;
}

displayQuery();
```

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <script src="fetchAPI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="mongoDB.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
        <body>
            <div class="my-grid">
            <p class="span-three">
                NOTE: ticker AAPL is just arbitrary
                Stock: <input id = "ticker" value = "AAPL"></input>
                <br/>
                <button onclick="displayQuery()" id= "submit" >Submit</button>
                <p id="query"></p>
            </p>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is server side only. You are trying it to call it in a front page. These are different things.

In order for your webpage to load data from your db you should create an API . The api would retrieve the data and send it back to you

Here is a link from an official forum
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/why-doesnt-mongodb-work-with-client-side-js/9062